# Can Windows Form C++ read images from folder and process it?

Tags: c++, winforms, opencv, user-interface

I do some image processing for my final project. First, I detect image, cropping the object and save the result into folder. After that I need to read all the images in that folder and do the segmentation process at the same time. And save the result again. Here is my code :

```
        private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        cv::String path("E:/result/*.jpg");
         vector<cv::String> fn;
         cv::glob(path, fn, true); // recurse
         for (size_t k = 0; k < fn.size(); ++k)
         {

             cv::Mat src = cv::imread(fn[k]);
            
             cv::Mat lab;
             cv::cvtColor(src, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);
             
             sprintf_s(file_name, "E:/Result2/s%u.jpg", k + 1);
             imwrite(file_name, lab); 
         }
         waitKey(0);} }
```

I successfully running the program using windows console application. But, when I copy the code into windows form, I can't find the result of segmentation in folder. There is no error and break when I run the program.
Thanks a lot for your Help.

Comment: Probably a good idea to show the definition of `file_name`.  Is this an array or a pointer type?  If it's a pointer, did you allocate memory for it?  In either case, is it large enough to hold the full path including a null terminator?  If OpenCV throws exceptions, perhaps you should wrap the OpenCV calls in a try-catch block and log any exceptions that occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry I forget to write the type of file_name. Here my declaration of file_name `char file_name[200];` what should I do then? I really don't know what to do @paddy

Comment: Sorry, I think I know what's the problem now and fix it. It's my fault because I forget to double click the button, so I write the program in the wrong button. Thank you very much for your answer, I can learn a new knowledge about what type of variable and how to handle it @paddy